# What is the code of read() function in python?

Tags: python

I opened a file and used the read() function as :

```
file = open(r'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\bigmountain.txt')
print(file.read())
```

I want to know how the `read()` function works in python. I got the code of other built-in functions but not `read()` over [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c). I also imported inspect module and used it's "getsource" function but to no use:

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(read()))
```

It says read not defined.

Please tell me how should I get the code of `read()` to know how it works.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried looking into [Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython)?

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_io/fileio.c

Comment: There is no builtin function `read()` in Python so there is no way you can see its code.

Comment: I am searching the link you both provided @brunodesthuilliers . Let me see if i get it

Comment: I was going to edit my answer, but  @brunodesthuilliers was quicker and his answer pretty much cover it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others already mentionned, there's no `read()` function in Python - what you're looking for (as confirmed in a comment) is the `read()` *method* of the `file` object (Python 2.x) or `_io.TextIOWrapper` object (Python3.x) , so the correct call to `inspect` would be (assuming Python 2.x):

```
inspect.getsource(file.read)
```

Also note that we're NOT calling (no parens) the method or function passed to  `getsource()`, as it would instead pass the function or method call result instead of the function or method itself.

But anyway: the code you're looking for is written in C, not in Python, so `inspect` can't do much for you here. You'll have to check the C source code here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_io/fileio.c